# Why does the article type (definite /indefinite) change the preposition before the word 'hotel' ?

Tags: prépositions, articles, formulation-idiomatique

> Nous dormirons **dans** **un** hotel.
>
> Nous dormirons **à** **l**'hotel.

Why does the preposition change in this case? Is it an inconsistency in your opinion? Do native French speakers occasionally find that unusual /strange, too?

Comment: Nous passerons la nuit à l'hôtel. for: spend the night at a hotel. Sleep at a hotel is unusual in English, too. Though I guess you could say. But when would you say it? Sleep in the hotel, not in the parking lot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Outside rare regionalisms, native speakers never find idiomatic phrases unusual or strange. This is by definition. "Strange" and "stranger" are related for a reason.

1. *On<sup>1</sup> dormira dans un hôtel* : There is an hotel where we will sleep. We probably already know which one.
2. *On dormira à l'hôtel* : The place where we are going to sleep is a "hotel" type of place. That's the plan. We might sleep in different hotels.
3. *On dormira à l'hôtel* (bis) : We will sleep in a specific hotel, the hotel well known to the people we talk to.
4. *On dormira dans l'hôtel* : We will sleep inside the hotel (not in the parking lot ;-)
5. *On dormira à un hôtel* : Not idiomatic. Unlike the three other sentences, no native speaker would say that (not from France at least).

If you name the hotel, the meaning cease to be generic:

6. *On dormira à l'Hôtel du Nord* : Regular.
7. *On dormira dans l'Hôtel du Nord* : Weird (only a [single hit](https://www.wildspot.fr/gr20-corse-autonomie/) for *on dormira dans l'hôtel* with Google, from people used to sleep under the stars...).

<sup>1</sup>  <sub>Native speakers almost never use the first person plural in speech (even if some of us believe they do.)</sub>

Note also that this usage of a definite article for indefinite object is only possible when that object can logically be considered generic according to the verb used.

A hotel is a place where people sleep "by design", so ***on dormira à l'hôtel*** is synonymous of ***on dormira dans un/des hôtel(s)*** but when the object is not the one expected for the verb, the generic meaning doesn't work: ***on dormira à la gare*** can only be understood to mean, we will sleep at the train station we are talking about or at the only station there. On the opposite, in ***on dormira à la belle étoile*** (an idiom), the meaning can only be generic because there is no specific place with that name.

Same with a restaurant. ***On mangera au restaurant*** has either a generic or a specific meaning while for example ***on mangera à l'aéroport*** can't be used generically, that will happen on a given airport (we will eat at the airport we are talking about).

Comment: On dormira à l'hôtel ce soir. We'll sleep at **a hotel** tonight. That's the whole point of explaining an idiom to someone. The English and French differ in terms of the actual idiom. Je vais **au cinema les mardis**. I go to **a movie** or **the movies** on Tuesdays. But not: I go to the movie on Tuesdays.

Comment: @Lambie *The English and French differ in terms of the actual idiom*: Not a surprise, is it?

Comment: Of course. Your "dormira à l'hôtel" was an opportunity for you to explain it and you didn't. Yet, it is a major point.

Comment: @Lambie It is a major point for someone familiar enough with the English language, but maybe the OP finds the article inconsistent with their own language, not specifically English. That's why I prefer to explain in that reply the differences between the various possible combinations without referring too much to English-specific points. I do not use English as a reference here, but as a lingua franca. Of course, I do not say using English the way you suggest doesn't work, just that I chose a different method.

Comment: The bottom line for me and it is what I explained, is that in French, à, au, aux (marchés aux puces, etc.), à l'  is for making general idiomatic statements such as aller au restaurant. dans means à l'intérieure de.

Comment: Then we agree on that, I wrote *à l'hôtel* is for a type of place (i.e. generic) while *dans l'hôtel* means inside the hotel.

Comment: @jlliagre Thank you. This answer was quite informative. So, using definite article for an unknown object and using the indefinite article for a known object both are possible in French. Btw do you wonder why the preposition changes with the article? Do people ever question such type of things?

Comment: Most people do not question their mother tongue. They acquire vocabulary,  grammar and idioms by "impregnation", they are saturated with them so from there, most choices are not made consciously, memory and intuition decide. Learning a second language is another pair of shoes, We often try to find tricks and simple rules that would help us to accelerate our learning path. It can work, because grammarians do question their own language and manage to find rules and logic explaining how a language functions, but it doesn't always.

Comment: The preposition doesn't change the article, both *dans l'hôtel* and *à l'hôtel* are valid French. It's true *à un hotel* doesn't work that much but for example *je me suis arrêté **à une** station-service* is fine (I stopped at a gas station).

Comment: Watch out, "à un hotel" is generally not said alone, but becomes possible in other situation. Ex: "J'ai dormi à un hôtel de luxe", "J'ai dormi à un magnifique hôtel hier soir" or "Le locataire s'engage à décorer l'hôtel comme il sied à un hôtel de première classe".

Comment: @Simon Je ne connais pas la forme *j'ai dormi à un hôtel de luxe*. Je ne dis pas que ce n'est pas idiomatique quelque part, mais je ne l'ai simplement jamais entendu. Bien sûr, ça ne m'empêche pas de comprendre ce qui est dit.

Comment: @Simon "j'ai dormi à un hôtel" : Google ne retourne qu'une seule page.

Comment: *Comme il sied **à un hôtel** [..]*, là, pas de problème, c'est la bonne et la seule façon de le dire.

Comment: @jlliagre Je dois être tellement habituer à l'anglais que ça me semble normal, ou alors on le dit au Québec.

Comment: @Simon On n'en est pas à un hôtel près ;-) Ouais je pense que c'est _dormir/coucher à l'hôtel_, puis là on veut ajouter une épithète ou comme dans le seul exemple on voulait rajouter _sans borne_, et c'est long avec la relative de dire _où il n'y avait pas de borne_ et on connaît l'anglais mais le gars était de Bordeaux entk. À la belle étoile, à même le sol mais à l'hôtel ou dans un hôtel magnifique il me semble. Peut-être qu'on entend ça, ça ressemble à un calque, j'ai comme une hésitation étrange.

Answer (score 0):

- aller à l'école
- aller au travail
- aller au marché
- aller à l'église
- aller à la mer
- aller à l'hôtel [stay at a hotel, or go to a hotel]

Those are how one says the general and idiomatic idea of:
go to school
go to work
go to the market
go to church
go to the seaside

- dormir dehors et pas dans un hotel (sleep outside not in(side) a hotel)
- dormir dans une boîte (sleep in a box) (a cat, for instance)
- dormir dans un lit, pas dans un hamac (sleep in a bed, not a hammock)

**dans** really means **in as in inside of**, within the confines of.

- Le corps s'est trouvé *dans l'hôtel*, pas dans la rue.
- The body was found *inside the hotel*, not in/on the street.
- Le chien s'est perdu dans le bâtiment. [in or inside the building]

If you are staying *at a hotel*, it would be: **à l'hôtel**, and not dans l'hôtel.

And, if you want to express the *general idea of dining or eating at **a** restaurant* or *dining or eating out** in French, please notice: aller au restaurant.

We went out for diner last night.
Nous sommes allés **au restaurant** hier soir.

The generic ideas as in the list above all take the definite article in French, and only "go to the market"  takes one in English, for example.

(What was specified in the other answer about *we* being *on* is often true.)

Comment: I removed the whole conversation because some people are unable to talk to each other nicely. It is a shame, but I will do it more and more often if I have to.