# Why is it « étudier à l'université » but « étudier dans la meilleure université » ?

Tags: prépositions, formulation-idiomatique

In one Duolingo.com exercise...

1. The original sentence was *"He'll be able to study at the city's best university"*.
2. I tried *"Il pourra étudier **à** la meilleure université de la ville"*, and it was not accepted.
3. Correct answer was *"Il pourra étudier **dans** la meilleure université de la ville"*.

The question is why doesn't **à** work here? To be honest **dans** does not sound natural to me at all.

Also, is it ever possible to use **à** in the place of **dans**? If yes would that result in change in the meaning?

Comment: You already asked a very similar [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/48675/1109) a few weeks ago.

Comment: @jlliagre Haha yes. I was looking for the question you linked, but couldn't find it somehow. Thought it was deleted. That is why I opened this one.

Comment: And right you were to open it, I just can't understand how anyone marked right *il pourra étudier dans la meilleure université de la ville*, *étudier* here is not used properly. If you used it in an exam situation it would be considered wrong.

Comment: @None Oh, you point out a mistake about word choice. Thanks.

Comment: @Xfce4 Yes, Although understandable, I doubt anyone  would use *étudier* in that sense nowadays. *J'ai étudié l'anglais à l'université* (I read English at university). *J'ai fait mes études à Cambridge*. (I studied at Cambridge). [More examples](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-french/study).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Il pourra étudier à l'université*.
→ Ici on ne parle pas d'un établissement en particulier mais de l'institution.

*Il pourra étudier dans la meilleure université (de la ville)*.
→ Ici il ne s'agit plus tant de l'institution, mais, dans la mesure où on a ajouté une précision qui permet de l'identifier, d'un bâtiment.

Ce serait la même chose avec le verbe aller :
*Il va à l'université. / Il va dans la meilleure université (de la ville).*

Remarque :
En français on dit plus volontiers ***faire ses études** à l'université* que ***étudier à** l'université* (qui pour moi sent la traduction de l'anglais).

---

*Il pourra étudier à l'université*.
→ In this sentence we're dealing with the university as an institution, we are not thinking of a precise building.

*Il pourra étudier dans la meilleure université (de la ville)*.
→ Since you add a precision (*la meilleure*) that helps concretise (a) building(s) we would use *dans*.

It would be the same with *aller*.
*Il va à l'université. / Il va dans la meilleure université (de la ville).*

Note :
In French we'd rather say  ***faire ses études** à l'université* than ***étudier à** l'université* (which to me sounds like a translation from English).

Comment: Yes, the main point about the idiomatic way of saying it is very good: faire des études.